# How do I create a view that replaces the labels from a table with new ones from a reference table in the view using common values?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to figure out a method to create a view using a reference table to match ID values from table 1 and table 2 and replace the original labels from table 1 with the labels in the reference table **in the view**. For example:

Currently, I managed to get the results I want by doing :

Table 1 language_labels

| active_ID | language_id | label_1 | label_2 | label_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SP | Hola | Chau | Comprar |
| 1 | EN | Hello | Bye | Buy |
| 1 | DE | Hallo | Tschuss | Kaufen |

Table 2 users:

| dep_id | active_id | username |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | username1 |
| 2 | 1 | username2 |
| 1 | 1 | username3 |
| 1 | 1 | username4 |

reference_table:

| dep_id | language_id | old_label | specific_label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | EN | Bye | Goodbye |
| 2 | EN | Buy | Purchase |

The result I want in my view (Based on the table and data provided the amount of records should be 12) :

| dep_id | username | active_id | language_id | label_1 | label_2 | label_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | username1 | 1 | DE | Hallo | Tschuss | Kaufen |
| 1 | username1 | 1 | EN | Hello | Bye | Buy |
| 1 | username1 | 1 | SP | Hola | Chau | Comprar |
| 2 | username2 | 1 | DE | Hallo | Tschuss | Kaufen |
| 2 | username2 | 1 | EN | Hello | Goodbye | Purchase |
| 2 | username2 | 1 | SP | Hola | Chau | Comprar |
| 1 | username3 | 1 | DE | Hallo | Tschuss | Kaufen |
| 1 | username3 | 1 | EN | Hello | Bye | Buy |
| 1 | username3 | 1 | SP | Hola | Chau | Comprar |
| 1 | username4 | 1 | DE | Hallo | Tschuss | Kaufen |
| 1 | username4 | 1 | EN | Hello | Bye | Buy |
| 1 | username4 | 1 | SP | Hola | Chau | Comprar |

Currently, I managed to get the results I want by doing :

```
SELECT
  users.dep_id,
  users.username,
  language_labels.*,
  CASE
    WHEN users.dep_id = 2
    AND language_labels.language_id = 'EN' THEN 'Goodbye'
    ELSE language_labels.label_2
  END AS label_2,
  CASE
    WHEN users.dep_id = 2
    AND language_labels.language_id = 'EN' THEN 'Purchase'
    ELSE language_labels.label_3
  END AS label_3
FROM
  language_labels
  INNER JOIN users on users.active_ID = language_labels.active_ID
```

However, I would like to do this in a less hard-coded way where I can insert the new specific labels in the reference table, and then it gets picked up by the view. I tried using the reference column values to equal the other table values (ex: `users.dep_id = referance_table.DepID` and so on but I get incorrect redundant results).

Comment: Why "*username4*" does not appear in your output?

Comment: @lemon Sorry if it was unclear I edited the post now. The result of this tables would be 12 I am just showing 3 as to avoid a bigger table. So "username4" would be in the result as well.

Comment: Show all 12 records if you're trying to get 12 records. Or reduce the size of your input table and make sample input and expected output full and coherent with each other. This will help people with troubleshooting.

Comment: Updating your output table has uncovered a hidden issue: there's no reference to "*dep_id*" = 3 or "*dep_id*" = 4 in your sample input tables. How do you get/compute those values?

Comment: I updated the table to only have dep_id 1 or 2.